# Retrieve current keybindings in extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing an VS Code extension which uses a webview. I'd like to retrieve the current list of keybindings so that I can reuse some of them within the webview to provide a more consistent experience to users.

Is there an API to retrieve the set of currently active keybindings? I am not able to find this information in the `vscode.settings` namespace.

Comment: define a new context variable so the user can replicate the key binding for the new context, in `package.json` copy the default key bindings for Win/Linux and Mac

Comment: The idea is to prevent the user from having to duplicate the keybinding configuration. Eg. if someone is using emacs keybindings I'd like to detect that without the user having to add any extra configuration.